# How to set delay to my method?

Tags: java, sprite

I'm trying to do something in Java and I need to wait for an amount of seconds.

```
private void PC() 
    {
        tab[rnd].setText("0");
        tab[rnd].setEnabled(false);                     
    }
```

This my method and I want to run it after 2 seconds.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(4000);` sleeps for 4 seconds

Comment: That pauses my entire program, how to use it to only this one method?

Comment: If you want to pause one part of the program while other parts are supposed to do their job during some period of time, you should make correct use of more than one thread in your program, but it might be a bit confusing if you are just starting you java learning. Your classes should implement Runnable or Callable interfaces and then maybe your methods should be correctly synchronized to avoid getting strange results when more than one method is able to change the same part of your program.

Comment: Możemy gdzieś porozmawiać prywatnie w rodzimym języku abym dokładnie wyjaśnił Ci mój problem?

Answer (score 0):

TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(x), (you can find it in java.util.concurrent), where x is amount of seconds you want to wait for another actions to process. Read about it in documentation, it offers even more time units.